# Why I found Composer error in larval when I run laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, dependencies, composer-php

when I run composer update command in mac system. it gives error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons[v4.10.0, ..., v4.13.3] require maatwebsite/excel ^3.0 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.0.0-alpha, ..., 3.1.x-dev].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.28, ..., 3.1.30] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.16.* -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.31, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.27 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.16 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.18.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.26 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.18.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.20, ..., 3.1.25] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.14 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.14.0, ..., 1.18.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.18, ..., 3.1.19] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.10 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.10.0, ..., 1.18.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.7, ..., 3.1.17] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, ..., 1.18.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.6] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.4 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.4.0, ..., 1.18.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.0.1, ..., 3.0.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.2 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.2.0, ..., 1.18.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.0.0-alpha, ..., 3.0.0] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.1 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.1.0, ..., 1.18.0].
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.1.0, ..., 1.18.0] require ext-zip * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.
    - Root composer.json requires yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons ~4.10 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons[v4.10.0, ..., v4.13.3].



Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Comment: `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.1.0, ..., 1.18.0] require ext-zip` - what have you tried to resolve this?

Comment: Just run `composer update -W`

Comment: I have tried "composer install --ignore-platform-reqs" and "composer update --ignore-platform-reqs" these two commands but getting new errors

Comment: tried "composer update -W" but getting same error.

Comment: "Getting new errors" is pretty vague. If you need help, share them. Also, why not install `ext-zip` such that you can properly use `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet`?

Comment: `--ignore-platform-reqs` allows you to ignore the PHP version set as target (e.g. the one you have on Production) and use the local one. It won't make a package work with a PHP extension that isn't installed. Office files are ZIP archives—you can't open them without ZIP libraries.